# gedit put BOLD text with Yellow Background on a script comment line

Tags: bash, gedit

Not a high-priority question but I'm curious why gedit today decided to make text bold with yellow background when I put in a comment line "# TODO" as shown below:

[image: gedit color TODO]

### Edit - Follow-up

After accepting the answer below I used the tips to have more BOLD text with yellow background in `gedit`:

[image: gedit bold text yellow background]

Comment: So are you saying it didn't use to do that?

Comment: @AndroidDev not saying that at all my friend. It was the first time I put "TODO" into a bash script file and was just curious about the syntax highlighting inside of a comment. It would seem the answer has just been posted below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not just `TODO` but `FIXME` and `XXX` will also highlight.

see this file line no 107 and line no 184

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/def.lang
```

You can add stings of your choice like `DATE`:

Open `def.lang` file and add DATE at `line 184` as shown below:

[image]

For changes to take place **CLOSE** your already opened document and reopen.
Now add `#DATE` in your document and it will highlight.

[image]

Comment: line 107 reads: "    <!-- Anything that needs extra attention; mostly the keywords TODO, FIXME and XXX -->". TODO and FIXME makes a lot of sense but XXX is usually associated with adult male entertainment / stress relief and I can't fathom for the life of me why that is there??? Irregardless thanks for the quick answer and I'll enjoy skimming this file.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: "adult **male** entertainment" Did you just assumed its gender. I just Googled and found out XXX means kisses apart from domain for porn. and thanks for quickly accepting the answer :p

Comment: Yeah I'm old school assuming the female entertainment would be "$$$"... All joking aside "XOXO" represents hugs and kisses. In all seriousness I still don't understand what "XXX" means in source code comments. My pleasure accepting the answer however I'd like to point out changing line 107 by adding "DESC, DATE, and UPDT" did not change highlighting in gedit within source file"

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix:  Updated my answer tried with `DATE`.

Comment: Ahhh.... the elusive line 184 and not line 107 as first posted. I've changed it and it works perfectly now thanks: "          <match>\b(FIXME|TODO|DATE|DESC|UPDT|NOTE|CALL|NAME|PATH)\b</match>
" Notice I took out "XXX" which I'll never use in source code.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452934/what-is-the-meaning-of-xxx) is for `XXX` mystery.

Comment: Interesting link you gave me. I still refuse to use XXX though and have just downgraded Python by one notch.